# How to enable php?

Tags: php

Any `PHP` code I try to write is just not executing at all

`WAMP` is OK, working and all services running

`php.ini` short tags are `On`

My file is in `.php`

`HTML` is working properly

I tried the simplest code possible... not working at all

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Pls show screenshot of your errors in wamp

Comment: post some of your code. Remember PHP is server side and java script is client side language.

Comment: Do you have at  least the homepage of WAMP ?

Comment: Did you try to open .php file by doubling clicking it like a .html file? php file won't work like that.

Comment: I can't find any way to post a screenshot here... is there a way or should I host it somewhere else?

For the WAMP page if you are talking about the page that appears when I type Localhost... then yes it appears properly, if you are talking of some other page then I don't know what it is.

And no I didn't doubleclick on the file I openned it throught the browser in localhost.